# Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How to perform Secondary sort on a Wordcount program so that the final output will be displayed in decreasing order ? (based on values)

Note: I am reading data from text file .
if i have to use composite key, Partitioner, comparator, how to use it for this question ? In online for many example has four or five input, example temperature

https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/secondary-sorting-aka-sorting-values-in-hadoops-mapreduce-programming-paradigm/

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming that the mapReduce program is in fact partitioning and sorting. To sort in reverse order you just add an 'r' after the sort value as shown in `k1,1r`.

This means that mapReduce will sort alphabetically in reverse order starting from z and going down to a.

```
-D mapreduce.partition.keycomparator.options="-k1,1r -k2,2 -k3,3"
```

Just make sure the partitioning and sorting is initially actually being done.